# Loopback before save update all instance

Tags: hook, instance, loopbackjs, strongloop

Hey all quick question about before save on UpdateAll

Hypothetically I have a customer model, that hasMany Orders. In an operation hook monitoring before save of the Customer I'm trying to create an order automatically. The trick is that I'm trying to do this when doing customers UpdateAll

Based on the docs I see there's no way to get the id of the current instance of the customer

But is there a way to do something like `ctx.instance.orders.create(data);` ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe in case like this, using `persist` hook will make more sense. You can access the id via `ctx.currentInstance.id`. This hook is triggered by operations that persist data to the datasource, including update.

```js
MyModel.observe('persist', function(ctx, next) {
  if (ctx && ctx.currentInstance.id) {
    // create order here
  } 
  next();
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for updateAll unfortunately... only data shown in ctx is `where` and `data`.. :/

Answer (score 0):

`updateAll` is an alias function of `update`.

You can try something like,

```
Customer.observe('before save', (ctx, next) => {
    if (ctx.instance && ctx.instance.id ) {
      // create order here
    }
    next();
  });
```

`ctx.instance.id` is avaialble only when you pass it.

i.e

`Customer.update({id: 1}, {name: 'New Name'})` -in this case `ctx.instance.id` will be available.

`Customer.update({name: 'New Name'})` - in this case `ctx.instance.id` won't be available. Also this will update name of all the customer.

Comment: Unfortunately the request I'm trying to intercept is `Customer.updateAll({id: {inq: [1,2,3...]}});` and there is no instance in before save :/

Comment: Yes. Because update doesn't fetch anything from db. It uses database update operation. 

One possible workaround would be to override the updateAll function for Customer Model.

Comment: If it uses database update operation though how do the operation hooks get triggered? for example when I do id: `({id: {inq: [1,2,3]}});` then I do see the operation hooks before/after save trigger 3 times... no way to access the currently affected instance?